# A self-proof of Vapnik - Chervonenkis theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, probability-distributions, machine-learning

**Theorem**: For every $\varepsilon >0$, with the probability greater than $1-\varepsilon$
\begin{align*}
    R_p(\hat{g}_{n,\mathcal{G}}) - R_{p}(g^*_{p,\mathcal{G}}) \le 2 \sqrt{\dfrac{2V_{\mathcal{G}}(2n) \ln(4(2n+1)\varepsilon^{-1}) }{n}}
\end{align*}
where $V_{\mathcal{G}}(N) = \sup_{\mathbb{X_N} \in \mathcal{X}^N} V_{\mathcal{G}} (\mathbb{X_N})$ with $\mathbb{X_N} = \left\{x_1,x_2,\ldots x_N\right\}$. The notation $V_{\mathcal{G}}$ denotes for the VC-dimension of $\mathcal{G}$.

**My proof**: (This proof was confirmed to be wrong by my lecturer. He pointed out the mistake was at the **union bound** after (1.1). I wonder if you could help me fix this point by using Rademacher complexity)

Before going to the proof, let us recall some definitions, and lemmas we are going to use.

**Lemma** (Sauer).
For all $S = \left\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\right\} = \mathbb{X_N}$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \vert T_{\mathcal{G}}(S)\vert &\le \sum_{k=0}^{V_{\mathcal{G}}(\mathbb{X_N})} C^k_N\\
    & \le \begin{cases}
        (N+1)^{V_{\mathcal{G}}(\mathbb{X_N})} & \text{, if } N> V_{\mathcal{G}}(\mathbb{X_N})\\
        2^N & \text{, if } N \le V_{\mathcal{G}}(\mathbb{X}_N)
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

**Lemma:** (Symmetrization).
Let $l$ be the loss function that
\begin{align*}
    a \le l(y,y') \le a+1,\ \forall y,y' \in \mathcal{Y}.
\end{align*}
Let $\mathcal{D'}_n = (x'_i,y'_i),\ i=\overline{1,n}$ be a sample independent of $\mathcal{D}_n$ with the same law. Then for all $t \ge \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{n}}$
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}}\vert \hat{R}_n(g) - R_p(g)\vert > t\right) \le 2\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}}\left\{\hat{R}_n(g) - \hat{R}'_n(g)\right\} > \dfrac{t}{2}\right),
\end{align*}
where $\hat{R}_n(g):=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n l(y_i,g(x_i))$, $\hat{R}'_n(g):=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n l(y'_i,g(x'_i))$.

**Back to the main proof.**
Let $nt^2 = 2V_{\mathcal{G}}(2n)\ln\left(4(2n+1)\varepsilon^{-1}\right)$. Then, we would like to prove that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(R_p(\hat{g}_{n,\mathcal{G}}) - R_p(g^*_{p,\mathcal{G}}) > 2t \right) \le \varepsilon. \tag{*}
\end{align*}

Firstly, we use the following fact
\begin{align*}
R_p(\hat{g}_{n,\mathcal{G}}) - R_p(g^*_{p,\mathcal{G}}) \le 2\sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}}\vert \hat{R}_n(g) - R_p(g)\vert,
\end{align*}
and obtain that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(R_p(\hat{g}_{n,\mathcal{G}}) - R_p(g^*_{p,\mathcal{G}}) > 2t \right) \le \mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}}\vert \hat{R}_n(g) - R_p(g)\vert > t \right).
\end{align*}
Next, by using the symmetrization lemma, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}}\vert \hat{R}_n(g) - R_p(g)\vert > t \right) \le 2 \mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}}\left\vert \hat{R}_n(g) - \hat{R}'_n(g)\right\vert > \dfrac{t}{2} \right). \tag{1.1}
\end{align*}

Let us consider the trace of $\mathcal{G}$ on $(\mathbb{X}_n,\mathbb{X}'_n)$, denotes $T_{\mathcal{G}}(\mathbb{X}_n,\mathbb{X}'_n)$.

Each element of $T_{\mathcal{G}}(\mathbb{X}_n,\mathbb{X}'_n)$ is a sample $\left\{x_{j_1},x_{j_2},\ldots,x_{j_K}\right\}$ with $K \le 2n$. To each of these elements, we can associate a prediction $g \in \mathcal{G}$ such that $g(x_{j_k})$ = 1, $\forall k \in [K]$. We just built a bijection between $T_{\mathcal{G}}(\mathbb{X}_n,\mathbb{X}'_n)$ and a subset of $\mathcal{G}$, denotes $\hat{\mathcal{G}}_n$. With this notation, we have

$$\vert \hat{\mathcal{G}}_n\vert = T_{\mathcal{G}}(\mathbb{X}_n,\mathbb{X}'_n) \le (2n+1)^{V_{\mathcal{G}}(2n) 
 }.$$

Therefore, we can derive from (1.1) that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}}\vert \hat{R}_n(g) - R_p(g)\vert > t \right) &\le 2 \mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}}\left\vert \hat{R}_n(g) - \hat{R}'_n(g)\right\vert > \dfrac{t}{2} \right)\\
&=2\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{g \in \hat{\mathcal{G}}_n}\left\{\hat{R}_n(g) - \hat{R}'_n(g)\right\}> t/2\right)\\
&\le 2 \sum_{g \in \hat{\mathcal{G}}_n} \mathbb{P}\left(\hat{R}_n(g) - \hat{R}'_n(g)> t/2   \right) \tag{union bound}\\
&\le 2\vert \hat{\mathcal{G}_n}\vert \max_{g \in \mathcal{G}} \mathbb{P}\left(\hat{R}_n(g) - \hat{R}'_n(g) > t/2 \right)\\
& \le 2(2n+1)^{V_\mathcal{G}(2n)} \max_{g \in \mathcal{G}} \mathbb{P}\left(\hat{R}_n(g) - \hat{R}'_n(g) > t/2 \right)
\end{align*}
By substituting $\hat{R}_n(g) = \dfrac{1}{n}\mathbb{1}_{g(X_i)\neq Y_i}$ and using the Hoeffding inequality, we obtain the result in theorem.

Comment: Your click-bait title worked. I clicked to see how that VP theorem proved itself.

Comment: Can you show how you use Hoeffding inequality in the last step